# "Too many environment variables" when trying to launch a cywin shell from Hudson

Tags: windows, scripting, hudson, cygwin

I'm trying to execute a script on a Windows XP Hudson slave in cygwin. This is the shell command as it is configured in Hudson:

```
#!C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe
echo "hello"
```

It seems like it's having a problem getting cygwin to launch on the windows machine and I'm getting this error:

```
2 [main] bash 2692 C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe: 
*** internal error reading the windows environment - too many environment variables?
```

So has anyone else experienced this, and any ideas on how to get the script to run?

Comment: What happens if you remove the shebang line?  `#!C:\....`?  I don't remember cygwin accepting backslashes there, but it's been a while since I thought of that...

Comment: FWIW, what you've described works for me using the *Execute shell* build step (but not *Execute Windows batch command*).

Comment: @JimR: I tried removing the the shebang line, but then it didn't know where the bash executable was to run a bash script. So it looks like it can interpret backslashes in terms of  windows stuff. (My shebang line is just like the one here: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Shells

Comment: @Dave Bacher: I do have this in the Execute shell build step, I'm wondering if there is a version problem. I'm running cygwin 1.5.21 and Hudson 1.3.82, what are you running?

Comment: I'm on cygwin 1.5.21-2 and Hudson 1.388. For historical reasons (that I don't recall), I have my Windows+cygwin builds run a *Windows batch command* that calls `\cygwin\bin\bash -c "my_build_script param param param"`

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't be surprised if you hit this old error

> there is a big problem in Windows
>   nevertheless.  When using ASCII
>   functions to access the environment,
>   as Cygwin does, the environment is
>   silently cut off at 32K.

from http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-09/msg00646.html

You can also look at a workaround for starting emacs from a windows shortcut (same error message that you have). May be you can change your bash call to incorporate the cygwin run command as described in the following post.

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-03/msg00156.html